# Get the id of closest select element on button click..jquery

Tags: jquery

```
  <td class="col-sm-2">
          <select class="form-control newclass addvalue input_color"  id="sugar_id">
            <option value="">Select Value</option>
            <option value="ABSENT">ABSENT</option>
            <option value="PRESENT">PRESENT</option>
          </select>
       <div id="sssugar_id">
         <input id="myInput1" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Fill  Value Or Select Dropdown" style="margin-top: 5px;border-color: green;border-width: medium;" type="text">
        <button type="button" id="mybtn1" class="btn btn-success button_class" style="margin-top: 5px;" onclick="addtest(1)">ADD</button>
       </div>
  </td>
```

I am appending input and button dynamically, how can I get the id of the closest select element on a button click?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button_class').click(function() {
   alert($(this).parent().prev().attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prev()` if you're sure they're right next to each other. (This should be fastest.)

```
$('#mybtn1').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).prev('select').attr('id'));
});
```

This gets the previous element.

If `<select>` was after `<button>` then you can find it like this:

```
$('#mybtn1').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).next('select').attr('id'));
});
```

If there's a chance that there will be another element in between, you could use `.siblings():`

```
$('#mybtn1').on('click', function(){
var id = $(this).siblings('.YourClass').attr('id');
});
```

This will get all siblings inside the same  with the desirable class.

Comment: there is no class specified for siblings...only one div element in between